# Issues with DNS target and routing

Tags: heroku, dns, routes, cname

I've got myself a domain, I've set up the CNAME to point to the DNS target provided by HEROKU. But when I follow the url lewismorgans.uk I am being routed to a page saying "There is nothing here yet, build something amazing".

I've not experienced this before on HEROKU, was looking for some advice?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Did you set up `lewismorgans.uk` or `www.lewismorgans.uk` in the Heroku console? They are, on a technological level, entirely different.

Comment: So in the Heroku it's set up as just lewismorgans.uk and then the DNS target, which I supplied to my DNS settings for my other provider.

Comment: OK, that's your issue, then. You've pointed `www.lewismorgans.uk` at Heroku, but Heroku is set up to expect `lewismorgans.uk` without the www. Add the `www.lewismorgans.uk` domain in the Heroku console, and point it at the new DNS they give you. (It will be different.)

Comment: Thanks very much for your help buddy, that totally fixed it! Appreciate you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question resolved by @ceejayoz.

Must include "www." in the host name on HEROKU.